# Split keyboard like iMessage app on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I am trying to have the same style of split keyboard like the iMessage app on the iPad.  If you split the keyboard, it seems like the two keyboards are still connected to each other.  This is different when I split the keyboard in YouTube app.

Also, the input field is right above the split keyboard on the right.  In addition, if you drag the split keyboard up and down, the input field also moves along with the split keyboard.  Is Apple using it's own custom keyboard?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [UITextView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html), specifically the `inputAccessoryView`.

When you set an input accessory view to your text view (or [UITextField](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html)) it will be attached to the keyboard, just as you described
Other example of it is safari's search field.

The trick in iMessages in the iPad is that the input accessory view is aligned to the right which is not a problem, you can have a big transparent inputAccessoryView containing the right aligned and visible view :)